# Get rowcount after rows are inserted in SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, rowcount

I need to get rowcount after an insert. In my stored procedure I am inserting values from one table into another based on an `IN` condition.

After that insert, I want to get the row count for each `IN` variable that it inserted.

If I use `sql%rowcount`, I get the combined count, so how many rows it inserted for `addrtype = H` and `addrtype = O`.

```
INSERT INTO TABLEB (ID, USERNAME, CITY)
    SELECT B.ID, USERNAME, ADDRESS
    FROM TABLEB B
    WHERE B.CITY = 'XYZ'
      AND B.ADDRTYPE IN ('H', '0')
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Successfully LOADED data.');
```

Comment: Tag your question with the specific RDBMS you're using; `sql` is too broad.

Comment: Did you mean to insert into TABLEB from TABLEB?

Comment: @TomBoyd, It is already making an insert. I want to return how many rows inserted for ADDRTYPE 'H' and 'O', seperately. using Oracle SQL